# CRC-16/ARC from String in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters, crc, crc16

I have the c# code below

```
public string CRCCalculator(string dtc)
{
    ushort crc = 0x0000;

    byte[] data = GetBytesFromHexString(dtc);

    for (var pos = 0; pos < data.Length; pos++)
    {
        crc ^= data[pos];
        for (var i = 8; i != 0; i--)
        {
            if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0)
            {
                crc >>= 1;
                crc ^= 0xA001;
            }
            else
                crc >>= 1;
        }
    }
    return crc.ToString("X4");
}
```

But I need this in vb.net, I have personally tried converting it and I have converted plenty of c# code to vb.net in the past however I have not worked with ushort's and bits and such.

Here is the converted VB.net code:

```
Public Shared Function CRCCalculator(dtc As String) As String
    Dim crc As UShort = &H0
    Dim data As Byte() = getBytesFromHexString(dtc)

    Dim pos = 0
    Do While (pos < data.Length)

        crc ^= data(pos)

        Dim i = 8
        Do While (i <> 0)
            i = (i - 1)
            If (crc And &H1) <> 0 Then
                crc >>= 1
                crc ^= &HA001
            Else
                crc >>= 1
            End If
        Loop

        pos = (pos + 1)

    Loop

    Return crc.ToString("X4")

End Function
```

Instead of getting a value back I always get 0.

Comment: Can you share whatever you have converted to vb.net and tell us what issue you are facing in that?

Comment: Added @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: What about the code for GetBytesFromHexString

Comment: I know the code from the GetBytesFromHexString is working correctly. I believe it has something to do with the operators ^= and >>=

Comment: Can you share the code of `getBytesFromHexString` so that we can debug the code at our end with the proper logic

Comment: Did you debug the vb.net code and try to compare the variable values with the C# code? What difference did you notice?

Comment: You know solutions can have shared c# and VB projects, right? You could always just build this in a toolset dll and keep it in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think "^" does what you think it does. Use "Xor" instead.

[C# ^ operator reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator) - exclusive-or operator
[VB ^ operator reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/exponentiation-operator) - power-of/exponent operator